# Get sum of other model field base on condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I want to the get the sum of the total field of `ru.invoice` to be displayed on `ru.students` if the name field of `ru.students` is equal to `student_id` of `ru.invoice`.

I used the `browse` method but it does not work.

```
class ru_students(models.Model):
    _name = 'ru.students'
    _rec_name = 'code'

def _get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    pool_re = self.pool.get('ru.invoice')
    pool_rec = pool_re.browse(cr, uid, ids, [('name','=','student_id')],    
context=context)
    for field in self:
        for line in pool_rec:
            x = 0.0
            x += line.total
            field.payed += x

    name = fields.Char(string="Name")
    payed = fields.Float(compute="_get_total")


   class ru_invoice(models.Model):
       _name = 'ru.invoice'
       _rec_name = 'code'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('qty','unit_price')
    def get_total(self):
        for rec in self:
            x = 0.0
            x = rec.qty * rec.unit_price
            rec.total = x


student_id = fields.Many2one('ru.students','Student ID")
qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
unit_price = fields.Float(string="Unit Price")
total = fields.Float(compute="_get_totals",string="Total")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it didn't work"? Did you get an Exception? Did you get a different result than expected? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be careful don't mix API7 code with API8 code, use always API8 code if you can (besides, it's going to be much easier for you to use API8). I think you want this on your field `payed` (check the class `ru_invoice` too because I corrected some things there -*example: in `total` field you had written `_get_totals` in `compute` when you wanted to call `_get_total`*-).

```
class ru_students(models.Model):
    _name = 'ru.students'
    _rec_name = 'code'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('invoices')
    def _get_total(self):
        for student in self:
            student.payed = sum(
                invoice.total for invoice in student.invoices)

    name = fields.Char(string='Name')
    payed = fields.Float(compute='_get_total', string='Payed')
    invoices = fields.One2many(comodel_name='ru.invoice',
                               inverse_name='student_id',
                               string='Invoices of the student')


class ru_invoice(models.Model):
    _name = 'ru.invoice'
    _rec_name = 'code'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('qty', 'unit_price')
    def _get_total(self):
        for invoice in self:
            invoice.total = invoice.qty * invoice.unit_price

    student_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='ru.students',
                                 string='Student ID')
    qty = fields.Float(string='Quantity')
    unit_price = fields.Float(string='Unit Price')
    total = fields.Float(compute='_get_total', string='Total')
```

Comment: Thanks worked i was trying to calculate it without adding one2many field.

Comment: Each time you create a `Many2one` field, you should create the `One2many` field in the inverse table (even though sometimes is not necessary). I'm glad I was able to help you!

Comment: should it be get_total or _get_total?

Comment: @pourjour it should be `_get_total`.